# Доступные библиотеки Telegram User API на C#

Tags: c#, telegram

Подскажите существующие библиотеки на C#  для работы с  Telegram User API.
TLSharp  не предлагать,он достаточно сырой.
В планах реализовать собсветнное приложение для отправки сообщений и парсинга.
Хотелось бы найти аналог Telethon на Python, только на C#

Comment: Думаете на этот вопрос можно объективно ответить? Для вас вон "сырой", а для кого-то это может самый лучший. Как вы предлагаете дать нам четкий ответ на ваш вопрос? Да и не уж то нельзя в гугле написать `telegram c#` и найти то, что подойдет под ваши стандарты?

Comment: `для отправки сообщений и парсинга` Для этого сойдет любая библиотека, хоть напрямую с API Telegram работайте.

Comment: Не [оно](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot)?

Comment: Я говорю об User API - эмулирование действий пользователя.
Боты в телеграмм это одно, я же спрашиваю за юзерботов)

Comment: В таком случае вам нужны исходники любого подходящего клиента телеги, либо изучать клиентское API. Потому что в данном случае ваше приложение будет как раз исполнять роль клиента. Напишите свою библиотеку. [Ссылка](https://core.telegram.org/)